# I shall do my duty by him

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence

I shall do my duty by him

What is the force of the preposition **by**. I think its force is that of agency, but the answer given in my book is **direction**. I don't know how
Also is the usage of this preposition correct here?

If I write

I shall do my duty through him

Would it be grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

*through* is not correct here, in that the meaning is different from *by*. See definition 8b in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by):

> 8b : on behalf of
>
> > // did right *by* his children

"I shall do my duty *by* him" is kind of like "I have an obligation to him, so I will do what I can to honor it."

*through* doesn't work because in this context it would mean something more like "I myself will not do what I have to, but instead I will have him do it for me."